# Preventing keyring from remembering password during session for SSH with private key on Kubuntu

Tags: ssh, kubuntu, keyrings

Kubuntu 14.04

Whenever I attempt to SSH into a server with a private key, I am asked to

```
Enter password to unlock the private key
```

However, this then remembers the password until I completely log out, without giving me the option for it to be a one-time thing.

I'd like to prevent this dialog from opening when using keys for SSH.

I've tried

```
gconftool-2 --set -t bool /apps/gnome-keyring/daemon-components/ssh false
```

and

```
sudo ln -sf /dev/null /etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-keyring-ssh.desktop
sudo ln -sf /dev/null /etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-keyring-gpg.desktop
```

without any luck.

**Edit**

It would seem to be `gnome-keyring-daemon`, ignoring its setting to not do it for ssh.

Answer (score 1):

I've taken to stopping the process from running with a few lines inside my users' `.bashrc` file.

```
gkd="$(pidof gnome-keyring-daemon)"
if [ "_$gkd" != "_" ];then
    kill -9 $gkd
fi
```